# Linking containers with Mesos JSON file

Tags: docker, haproxy, mesos, marathon

I am trying to link my application container to my DB container when sending the JSON task description to the Marathon framework.

I've read up on this question from last year: [Linked Docker Containers with Mesos/Marathon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980582/linked-docker-containers-with-mesos-marathon)

The question is: I know Fig will be able to help me with this but I just wanna know if there is a way to link them on the Marathon framework? HAProxy might work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to link two containers, they have to run on the same host. Marathon currently does not support that. To me it sounds like you don't really need that. Instead you could just use service discovery mechanisms to make your db accessible to the other service. For this you can use haproxy, or try [mesos-dns](https://github.com/mesosphere/mesos-dns).